# Can all $\aleph_2$-dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ be isomorphic?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, reference-request

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. For a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we say that $A$ is $\kappa$-dense if $|A \cap (a, b)| = \kappa$ for every interval $(a, b)$. By Cantor, any two $\aleph_0$-dense sets are order-isomorphic.

If the CH holds, then there are many non-isomorphic $\aleph_1$-dense sets. However, Baumgartner showed that it is consistent with $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ that all $\aleph_1$-dense sets are isomorphic, giving a generalization of Cantor's result. My question is, can this be pushed further? Is it consistent with $2^{\aleph_0} \geq \aleph_3$ that all $\aleph_2$-dense sets of reals are isomorphic? And what about for larger cardinals still? Can we have the result for $\aleph_1$-dense sets and $\aleph_2$-dense sets simultaneously?

Baumgartner himself asked if all $\aleph_2$-dense sets of reals could be isomorphic in his [original paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm79/fm79111.pdf), which I found linked here on MO (all thanks to François Dorais). But I have been unable to find out if his question has subsequently been answered. If anyone knows the answer, or can provide a reference, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The consistency of *All $\aleph_2$-dense sets are order-isomorphic* is problem 15.14 in [Arnold Miller's list of problems](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/problems.pdf) (which he keeps up-to-date), and there is no indication there that any progress has been made on it. That's at least strong evidence that it's still open.

Comment: Shelah also mentions it among the most important open problems in "On what I do not understand (and have something to say): I"http://shelah.logic.at/files/666.pdf

Comment: I wonder why that PDF file is called "666".

Comment: @Andrej: I assume it's Shelah's 666th paper, but I'm willing to embrace a more exciting explanation.

Comment: [666] is Shelah's 666th paper, but of course there is some wiggle room that he uses to assign particularly interesting numbers to special papers.

Comment: I think the assignment of numbers to Shelah's papers is not done by Shelah himself but by Andrzej Roslanowski, who maintains the archive of Shelah's papers.  

Comment: Thank you Zach and Péter for the links. I'm surprised to find this is still open. 

Comment: Not quite, Andreas!  Saharon was quite involved with the choice of "666" for that paper...he thought it a fine joke! (He was working on this paper when I first started working for him in Jerusalem.)

Comment: Does anyone know the name of Shelah's 1000 paper?

Comment: @Mohammad: You can see Shelah's complete archive of papers here: http://shelah.logic.at/.

Comment: But I see now that Shelah 1000 is unnamed. Sorry---I guess that's why you were asking.

Comment: It seems that some progress is made on this problem by Justin Moore. See: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/abstract/cbgy-76 where the following abstract is given:
In 1973, Baumgartner proved that it is relatively consistent with ZFC that every two ℵ1-dense subsets of R are isomorphic. At the time, he asked whether a similar result can be obtained for ℵ2-dense subsets of R. In this talk, I will discuss some progress which has been made on this problem, indicating what is required of a model of set theory in which the continuum is at least ℵ2 and all ℵ2-dense sets of reals are isomorphic.

Answer (score 8):

In section 5 (Concluding remarks and recent developments) of the paper [Baumgartner's isomorphism problem for $\aleph_2$-dense suborders of $\mathbb{R}$](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~justin/Ftp/Baumgartner_aleph2.pdf), by Moore and Todorcevic, the following is stated:

> He (Itay Neeman) moreover tentatively announced that, in spite of the gap in the
>   present paper, he was able to show that if there is a weakly compact
>   cardinal, then there is a forcing extension in which $BA_{\aleph_2}$ and $MA_{\aleph_2}$
>   both hold.

If the claim is true, it means that the problem is solved now!!!

Also in the notes [Reflection of clubs, and forcing
principles at $\aleph_2$](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/trsyu3dj1vo2szc/AABjuwpy4FS99xV6zhj5-o-la/Neeman.Luminy2014.pdf?dl=0) by Itay Neeman, the last theorem stated the consistency of $BA_{\aleph_2}.$

Comment: Mohammad: Thank you for posting those slides. It's my understanding that people in the know, including Justin Moore (though I do not speak for him), believe that Neeman has succeeded in solving the problem. I spoke with Itay himself after I heard about his Luminy talk and he tentatively affirmed his solution. We'll have to wait for his paper, but it would seem likely the problem is resolved!

Comment: Thanks for the references, nevertheless, I have notice that Neeman hasn't publish any paper with the proof. Does anyone knows what happened?

Comment: Hi Iván. I think Neeman's paper is still forthcoming.

Comment: At the 6ESTC in Budapest Neeman just gave a lecture on this. He indicated that he is close to finish the paper. The lecture showed some of the many ideas of the long and complicated proof.

Comment: Any update regarding Neeman's paper?

Comment: @Lorenzo I don't know!